# Counting results from a search string MVC 3?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3, linq, search, controller

I am using MVC3 and have done a search facility in my controller.I have used the model first approach , what I want to be able to allow the user to search for results that contain the given keyword(s) in the data.
If there are no matches to the search term then display an appropriate message.
If there are matching stories:
Display a message like “7 items match your search criteria: 'XXXXX'”

Any help would be much appreciated , Thanks

would it be something like this but with use of the ViewBag to display a message?.

```
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(SearchString))
                   News = News.Where(s => s.Headline.Count(SearchString));

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `string.Contains` for partial string matching:

```
var matchingResults = News.Where(s => s.Headline.Contains(searchString));
int count = matchingResults.Count();
if(count == 0)
{
   //no matches
}
else
{ 
   //display message
}
```

Comment: Right il have a attempt at that how would I go about displaying a message displaying number of results please?

Comment: I got this error - Error 'StudentNewsGroupWebsite.Controllers.NewsController.Index(string, string)': not all code paths return a value

Comment: You have to return a view from your controller - maybe a good time to start with an MVC tutorial